# Get and set correct window position with node.js

Tags: node.js, nw.js

In the `close` event I persist the window position as follows:

```
localStorage.lastlayout = JSON.stringify({
  "left": win.x,
  "top": win.y,
  "width": win.width,
  "height": win.height
});
```

On start, I restore it with:

```
    data = JSON.parse(localStorage.lastlayout);
    win.moveTo(data.left, data.top);
    win.resizeTo(data.width, data.height);
```

The problem is the position is off. As far as I can tell, I get the *inner* position. When setting I set the *outer* position. The windowing title and borders only accounted for when setting.

As this is cross-platform code I cannot test it on all platforms (yet) and I don't know if it is possible to get the metrics of the windowing engine so that I can correct it programmatically (think about the user changing the DPI or theme on Windows).

Is there a way to compensate for this?

Comment: A similar code normally works fine on my Windows and Mac. Maybe in some place (package.json?) you set "frame" to false?

Comment: I have not set it at all. From the [documentation](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/manifest-format#frame) I don't see how this could help. I don't want to have a frameless window, I need the title and widgets. Do I miss something? I can't try it out right now, I don't have access to the code at the moment.

Comment: Have you seen the [wiki page on this](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Preserve-window-state-between-sessions)? I think remembering window position should be an option for [`position`](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/manifest-format#position) in the manifest, and for that matter, there should be an option to use the OS default.

Comment: No, I didn't. Thank you for pointing me to this page. I wonder why I couldn't find it despite thorough searching. What I have now is functionally the same but platform independent. I take metrics instead of sniffing (best practice is test if functionalities are available, not for a specific agent/platform). Also, there is no horizontal delta. On XFCE (for example, I tested several platforms/win-managers) there's a horizontal gap of 3 pixels (based on theme). So the definitive and elegant solution is to measure the window metrics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've nailed it. I detect the offsets in respect to a known position `(0, 0)` and then detract it from the desired position. It's not perfect but it works:

```
      win.resizeTo(128, 128);
      win.moveTo(0, 0);
      log("dbg", "win", "detected metrics: " + win.x + ", " + win.y);
      win.moveTo(data.left - win.x, data.top - win.y);
      win.resizeTo(data.width, data.height);
```

The initial resize is necessary for some reason. It looks like the title and borders are not drawn at all on some platforms if the window is not large enough. Next I move it to the origin. The `win.x` and `win.y` contain the offsets at this point. The second `moveTo()` uses the corrected coordinates and finally I resize the window to the actually desired size.